# Is GeoKettle still under development?

Tags: spatial-etl, geokettle

GeoKettle (http://www.spatialytics.org/projects/geokettle/) is (or was?) a very promising approach to spatial ETL with an intuitive graphical process design, at least introduced an open source equivalent to [FME from SafeSoftware](http://www.safe.com/). The last (and still actual) version 2.5 dates from Febr. 2013.

There is no contact form on the site, and the forum is under maintenance.

Does anyone know about the state of the project and if it is still under active development?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "We are not a formal GIS Software Support Site and are likely to close questions and recommend you seek official routes for support if you:
 - ask about licensing, pricing and/or release dates" https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  It would be fine to ask a question like this in the GIS Chat Room.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have had a look around on their [website](http://www.spatialytics.org/) and elsewhere. It has been three years since the last blog posting (February 5th, 2013) when version 2.5 of GeoKettle [was announced](http://www.spatialytics.org/blog/release-of-geokettle-version-2-5-spatialetl-spatialetl-gk25/).

The [mailing list for developers](https://sourceforge.net/p/geokettle/mailman/geokettle-devel/) on sourceforge.net does not have any entries after December 2012. The [mailing list for english speaking users](https://sourceforge.net/p/geokettle/mailman/geokettle-users/?page=1) had its last entry in september 2014. Last update on [the french user mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/geokettle/mailman/geokettle-users-fr/) on sourceforge.net was in august 2011. Their [website forum](http://forum.spatialytics.com/) seems to be down.

Download of the project from Spatialytics market seems to have been discontinued. Downloads are however [available on sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geokettle/) with the latest update prepared the 20th of April 2015.

Found a [mirror of the GeoKettel 2.0 code](https://github.com/icholy/geokettle-2.0) on Github with user [icholy](https://github.com/icholy). He could however inform me he is no longer using the system. The website has some info on [trac related to version 2.6](http://trac.spatialytics.com/geokettle/milestone/GeoKettle%202.6), but it seems to stop there.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geokettle suggests that the system is still in use by someone.

To me it looks like the project for some reason has been abandoned, but I will update this answer in case I hear otherwise.